# How Does Adaboost Work with Viola and Jones Algorithm?

Tags: c, algorithm, implementation

I am implementing a functional face detection algorithm in C using Viola and Jones algorithm. I'm having trouble understanding Adaboost to train a strong classifier.

I can detect all 5 basic haar-features in a single image (162336 in a 24x24 image) I'm pretty sure this is good and working, and my algorithm outputs and array containing all the features sorted.

Then, I started working on Adaboost and here's what I understand. We create a weak classifier (slightly better than random) and we make a linear combination of many weak classifier (approx 200) to get a strong classifier.

What I don't understand is how to create this weak classifier. From what I read online:

- Normalize the weights of our training examples (first round 1 by default)
- Then get a feature (here's one of my problem, do I have to process each feature of each training example ? (162336 * number of examples) that would be a lot of computing power no ? )
- "Apply" this feature to each image to get an optimal treshold and toggle (here's my main problem, I don't understand what "apply" means here, compare it with each feature of the image ? I really don't see what I have to do with it. Then, I don't understand what is the treshold and the toggle and that's where i'm looking for help)
- Then many more other things to do

I'm really looking forward your help to make me understand this!

Comment: 160000 times ten or a hundred shouldn't take very long right? Computers do billions of operations a second now... Profile, don't guess

Comment: @GradyPlayer saying that it shouldn't take very long is quite vague. Say if you have **1000** samples and **162336** features then the total number of times a loop has to run is **162336000**. Adding this to the operations that are to be performed inside the loop, the process could take a significant amount of time.

Comment: These links might help- https://code.google.com/p/facedetect-f-spot/source/browse/trunk/libfspot/AdaBoost.c?r=16, https://github.com/astromme/AdaBoost, http://codingplayground.blogspot.in/2009/03/adaboost-improve-your-performance.html Also, do note that Computer Vision questions are not very popular on SO. One of my questions has been lying unanswered for a long time now. You will have to search elsewhere for this. :)

Comment: Thanks for your answers, i'll give it a look :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should have answered my own question faster, but I've forgot about it. It was a project for my computer science school so I can provide answers.

Adaboost is in fact fairly simple when you understand it.

First you need to detect features inside every images in your base (we used 4000 images to have a large set) you can store them if you have enough memory or process them when you need them in you program. For 4000 images with 5 haar features inside we used more than 16Gb of RAM (Code was written in c, but no memory leak, it was arrays of double)

The training algorithm assign a weight to an image. That weight represent the difficulty for the algorithm to make a good prediction (face or no face).

Your training algorithm will be composed of rounds (200 rounds is fine to have 90%+ of good prediction).

At the first round every image possess the same weight because the algorithm never worked on them.

Here is how a round goes:

1. Find the best haar feature among X (for each type) in each image. To do this, compare each feature to the same one (same type, dimension and position) on every image and see if it is a good or bad prediction. The feature with the best prediction inside the X features is the best one, keep it stored.You will find 5 best features per images because there is 5 type combine them in a single struct and it is your **weak classifier**
2. Calculate the weighted error of the classifier. The weighted error is the error of the weak classifier applied to each image while taking in account the weight assigned to each image. In later rounds, the image with a bigger weight (the algorithm made lot of mistakes about this image) will be taken much more into account.
3. Add the weak classifier to a strong classifier (which is an array of weak classifiers) and its alpha. The alpha is the performance of the weak classifier and is determined with the weighted error. With the alpha, weak classifier which were made at later stage of the algorithm when the training is harder will have more weight in the final prediction of the strong classifier.
4. Update the weight of each image according to the prediction of the weak classifier you just created. If the classifier is right the weight goes down otherwise it goes up.

At the end of the 200 rounds of training, you will possess a strong classifier composed of 200 weak classifier. To make a prediction about a single image, apply each weak classifier to the image and the majority wins.

I voluntarily simplified the explanation but the majority is here. For more informations look here, it really helped me during my project: http://www.ipol.im/pub/art/2014/104/article.pdf

I suggest every person interested in AI and optimisation to work on a project like that. As a student it made me really interested in AI and made me think a lot about optimisation, which I never did before.